# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.fx'

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, torch, yolo

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.fx'**

PyTorch version is 1.7.0 and i try to tun this command:

```
python3 detect.py --source inference/images/horses.jpg --cfg cfg/yolor_p6.cfg --weights yolor_p6.pt --conf 0.25 --img-size 1280 --device 0
```

it gaved me this error:

> from torch.fx import symbolic_trace

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.fx'

In first, i install torch 1.8.0 but when i have **“RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED - PyTorch”**; so, i install torch 1.7.0 to solve this problem and it solved.

I read something like that: *“torch.fx comes with torch 1.8.0”* but i can not upgrade because of “RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED - PyTorch” error.

How can i solve this problem: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.fx'** ?

Comment: i solve this problem. the torchision version did not match the torch version and i fixed it, so, it solved. but now, i'm taking “RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED" error again. How can i solve this ?

Comment: if you have new problem then you should create new question on new page - and you will have more space to describe problem (with all details and FULL error message)